# Debug help (javascript beginner)

Tags: javascript

Here is my code I'm working on for a class. Any help or advice would be great thanks. Can't figure out why it is not working.

(I'm using this as a filler because it said my post was mostly code any and needed more details)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>School Year?</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*  Input: Name and Credits
*   Process: Use if command (keyword) and logic operaters to calculate school year.
*   Output: The student’s name and year in school.
*/

function schoolyear(){
var name = document.getElementById("name").value ;
var credits = document.getElementById("credits").value ;
var c = parseFloat(credits);

if (c >= 0 && c < 30) {
    year = "freshmen";
} 
else if (c >= 30 && c < 60) {
    year = "sophomore";
}
else if (c >= 60 && c < 90) {
    year = "junior";
}
else (c >= 90) {
    year = "senior";
}   
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = year;

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1> Find out what year of school your in based on credits. </h1>
Please input your name <input type ="text" id= "name"></br>
Please input your amount of credits earned <input type ="text" id= "credits"></br>
<button type = onclick="schoolyear()"> Find out </button></br>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's an error here : `<button type = onclick="schoolyear()">`

Comment: *"I'm using this as a filler because it said my post was mostly code any and needed more details"* It wasn't wrong.

Comment: I fixed the button I think <button type ="button" onclick ="schoolyear()"> but its still not working?

Answer (score 1):

So after I went through your code I saw two errors:

```
<button type= onclick="schoolyear()"> Find out </button></br>
```

Remove "type="

```
<button onclick="schoolyear()"> Find out </button></br>
```

and change this from

```
else (c >= 90) {
year = "senior";}
```

to

```
else if (c >= 90) {
year = "senior";}
```

Tip: There is no need to define "credits" twice, you can just shorten it to this;

```
var c = document.getElementById("credits").value;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, your awesome!

Comment: You're welcome @Jice! Would you mind setting the answer to "accepted"? Appreciate it, thanks :)